# Display back-end errors in python flask

Tags: python, flask, python-webbrowser

I had a simple flask program that used to uploads image and runs at the backend, in this if any errors occur at the program it does not display the error instead it shows as process end.

My flask program as below:

```
import os
from app import app
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import shutil
import sys
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])
import subprocess, shlex
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the files part
        if 'files[]' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
        count = len(files)
        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                #log_file(filename)
                                
        flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
        ocr_detection(count)
        return redirect('/')
                
        

def ocr_detection(count):#OCR
        try:
             print('Starting OCR Detection')
        
             proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python pipeline.py"))
             out = proc.communicate()
             flash('JSON CREATED FOR '+str(count)+' PLAN(S)')
             print('OCR Detection ends')
       except Exception as e:
             flash(str(e))
                              
if __name__ == "__main__":

        app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD']=True
        app.run(host='192.168.105.4',debug=True,use_reloader=False)
```

If any error occurs in the backend like this

[image]

It shows the message like `'JSON CREATED FOR 10 PLAN(S)'` `'OCR Detection ends'`, I want to display the errors in web page that shows in command promt.

Answer (score 0):

return error to the client with try-except

```
@app.route('/error_page')
def error_return():
    try:
        #some code
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Comment: can you explain in detail? I cannot understand, where should I call this function

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your code in a try/except clause as such:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():

    try:
      //Your code
    except Exception as e:
      //Prints error message
```

You can read more about how try except works in python [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Also, if you want to display your error message on Flask view, you can use Flash which can help you [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/)

Comment: I used try...exception in my code and doesn't through error

Comment: Can you please update your code with the try clause ?

Comment: From the code it seems that the exception is being thrown before entering the OCR detection function. Start by putting the try clause in function upload_file() first and then you can trace the complete error cause.

Comment: As you said I changed my code and still not display the error